# Ubuntu 16.04 troubleshooting with NAT network configuration

Tags: ubuntu, dns, routing, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox 5.1.14.

I'm trying to get access to internet (just a simple setup) but I'm having routing/dns problems. I've tried doing a full check: ping my router (success), ping google DNS (host unreachable), ping google url (host unreachable) and nslookup google (success).

Here is my output:

[image]

So, Is that a DNS problem? If I had connection to the internet the `ping 8.8.4.4` should be successful.

EDIT:

I have found that it is probably a proxy issue, I have access to my intranet applications.

Answer (score 0):

The 192.168.56.1 address makes me think that you are using [Host Only](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) mode.  This mode does not allow external network access.

You likely will need to use a different networking mode.

Comment: I'm on NAT 100%. I added an update to my post because I can access to my intranet applications so I guess I'm missing vpn/proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by configuring my proxy **manually**.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please [edit] this answer to provide enough detail that it will be able to help somebody else in the future.